# Extensions of groups with solvable word problem

Tags: group-theory, computability

Is there a reasonably simple (to describe) example of a short exact sequence of finitely generated groups $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow H\rightarrow 1$, where $N$ and $H$ have solvable word problem, but $G$ does not?
I assume that solvability of the word problem is not closed under extensions, although for some reason I cannot find anywhere an explicit reference. So I would be happy to see some counter-example.

Comment: Did you attempt to write an algorithm for the WP for $G$? The approach is quite straightforward.

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, I didn't. Are you saying that it is actually closed under extensions?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well, we can choose generators $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m\}$ of $G$, where $a_i$'s lie in $N$ and generate $N$, and $b_i$'s don't lie in $N$ and $b_i^{-1}b_j\notin N$, for $i\neq j$. Then given a reduced word $w$ in these generators we first run an algorithm solving the WP for $H$ considering only $b_i$'s from $w$. If the algorithm says that this is non-trivial, we are done. Otherwise, there is an algorithm that can produce equivalent $w'$ written in $a_i$'s only and then we run an algorithm solving the WP for $N$. Is it just this?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Actually, I am not sure. Maybe the argument in the comment above works if the short exact sequence splits and $G$ is a semi-direct product of $N$ and $H$. But otherwise, I don't see it.

Comment: Why would not it work in general? I would modify it however, so that the two Turing machines work simultaneously (and one of them would eventually stop).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Using the notation I wrote in the comment above, suppose we are given a word $w$ just in $b_i$'s and the algorithm for the WP for $H$ tells us that it represents a trivial element in $H$. So $w$ now represents some element of $N$, but in order to decide whether it is trivial we would need an algorithm that re-writes it as a word in $a_i$'s. I don't see how to do it.

Comment: You first rewrite $w$ in the form $u(a_1,a_2...)v(b_1, b_2,...)$ using normality of $N$. Then you run two TMs for the words $u, v$ in unison. Say, if it happens that $w\in N$, then eventually the 2nd TM will tell you that $v\equiv_H 1$ and, thus, you are left with  $u(a_1,a_2...)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan In that case the second TM will tell me that $v\equiv_H 1$, but still $v$ can represent a non-trivial element of $N$, so it is not enough to consider just $u$. The first TM can tell me that $u=_N 1$, but still $w$ represents something non-trivial in $N$.